# How to retrieve multiple users at once with the GitHub API?

Tags: github, github-api

I'm able to get a single user, or all users created since a timestamp, or where there is some search match with the GitHub API.

https://developer.github.com/v3/users/#get-a-single-user
https://developer.github.com/v3/users/#get-all-users
https://developer.github.com/v3/search/#search-users

What I haven't been able to figure out is if there is a way to send something like a list of logins and get back all of those users at once.

My use case is that I'm pulling back a list of members off of an org.  This provides me with enough data that I could loop through each individual user and get the detailed user data that I need this way, but I would rather not be hammering GitHub's API with a bunch of extra requests if it is not necessary.

Answer (score 9):

Using [GraphQL API v4](https://developer.github.com/v4/), you could build a dynamic query with as many user you have in your array & use [aliases](http://graphql.org/learn/queries/#aliases) for each one :

```graphql
query {
  user1: user(login: "aisalmi") {
    ...UserFragment
  }
  user2: user(login: "bertrandmartel") {
    ...UserFragment
  }
  user3: user(login: "molokoloco") {
    ...UserFragment
  }
}

fragment UserFragment on User {
  login
  name
}
```

I also use a [fragment](http://graphql.org/learn/queries/#fragments) to avoid field duplication

[Test it in the explorer](https://developer.github.com/v4/explorer/?query=query%20%7B%0A%20%20user1%3A%20user(login%3A%20%22aisalmi%22)%20%7B%0A%20%20%20%20...UserFragment%0A%20%20%7D%0A%20%20user2%3A%20user(login%3A%20%22bertrandmartel%22)%20%7B%0A%20%20%20%20...UserFragment%0A%20%20%7D%0A%20%20user3%3A%20user(login%3A%20%22molokoloco%22)%20%7B%0A%20%20%20%20...UserFragment%0A%20%20%7D%0A%7D%0A%0Afragment%20UserFragment%20on%20User%20%7B%0A%20%20login%0A%20%20name%0A%7D%0A)